# iTextSharp processing, but it does not appear in Android pdf

Tags: android, asp.net, itext

Good morning,
a click, elaborate a form (in part) where I run the algorithm to process a iTextSharp fil pdf, where I post the following instructions:

```
 Dim doc As New Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4.Rotate, 10, 10, 60, 30)
 Dim pdfFilePath As String = Resources.FrmParcheggio.Soste & ".pdf"
 Dim Response As HttpResponse = HttpContext.Current.Response
 Response.Clear()
 Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
 Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" & pdfFilePath)
 Dim wri As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, Response.OutputStream)
 Dim Intestazione As New MyPageEventHandler
 Intestazione.Cliente = HttpContext.Current.Session("NomeCliente")
 Intestazione.NomeReport = Resources.FrmParcheggio.TitoloReport
 wri.PageEvent = Intestazione
 doc.Open()
 ' various processing
 doc.Close()
```

My problem is that in different browsers (win and mac os) and it works with ios, but Android is all worked out but the PDF is not shown ... Why? There is some mistake?
Many thanks to those who respond.
david

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
```

It should be:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
```

You're also asking the browser to show the PDF inline:

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" & pdfFilePath)
```

Not all browsers can show PDFs inline. Maybe you want to make sure that it is opened outside the browser:

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & pdfFilePath)
```

Moreover, some browsers don't like binary content without knowing in advance how many bytes will be sent. That's why you'll see plenty of iText code where the PDF is first created in memory (using a `MemoryStream`) which allows setting the content length before writing the first PDF byte.

Finally: did you check different Android devices? Not every device has a PDF viewer and you need a PDF viewer to render the PDF.

*In any case:* this isn't an iTextSharp problem because, as you say yourself, the PDF shows up correctly in different browsers.

Comment: ok, I tried it on another Android and everything works! many thanks Bruno Lowagie